# Ansible: is there a way to have variables without defaults?

Tags: ansible

I've got some vars:

```
vars:
    var1: foo
    var2: bar
```

I'd like to have a var3, but I'd like for it to be set a runtime.

- I don't want to use a `vars_prompt` because that would require user intervention.
- I want to force that when this playbook is called, it's called with an `--extra-vars var3=bat`.
- I don't want to just reference `{{ var3 }}` somewhere, because I like the idea of this playbook being somewhat self-documenting.
- I'd rather not do some sort of `include_vars` file, unless that's what this situation calls for and is standard.
- I believe the following is not allowed:

  ```
  vars:
      var1: foo
      var2: bar
      var3
  ```

What do I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `assert` is good enough as workaround?
It gives good readability of playbook.
Add it as your first task:

```
- assert:
    that:
      - var3 is defined
      - var3 in ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Comment: This seems like an awesome workaround! Can you think of any others? I'm curious if they exist

Comment: Nope, I usually do it this way.

Comment: If you want it to be self-documenting, this is how to do it. Otherwise, just use the variable in your playbook and give instructions in the readme. If they don't include it, Ansible will throw an error for var not defined.